# Pundit and ActiveRecord merged joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, pundit

I am using the Pundit gem to role scope my application and have found some difficulties merging ActiveRecord queries. I am working with Rails 5.1.4.

See I have three models, lets say Classroom, Student and Exam with:

- Classroom has_many :students & has_many :exams, through: :students
- Student belongs_to: :classroom & has_many :exams
- Exam belongs_to: :student

Each have a policy scope with varying queries that I want to merge together to ensure a user has access to the Exam model that's within the Student scope, that's also within the Classroom scope.

Pundit let us do that by passing whatever ActiveRecord relationship from the controller to the Scope class inside a scope variable.

With that in mind, my scope classes appear as follow:

```
class ClassroomPolicy::Scope
  def resolve
    if user.reviewer?
      # A reviewer can only see specific classes
      scope.where(type: :exam).where(reviewer_id: user.id)
    end
  end
end

class StudentPolicy::Scope
  def resolve
    if user.reviewer?
      # A reviewer can only see students from classes he's allowed in
      scope.joins(:classroom).merge(policy_scope(Classroom))
    end
  end
end

class ExamPolicy::Scope
  def resolve
    if user.reviewer?
      # A reviewer can only see/grade exams from students he supervised
      scope.joins(:student).merge(policy_scope(Student))
    end
  end
end
```

All works well, if I do `policy_scope(Exam)`, I do get all exams from students who where inside a reviewer's classroom.

The issue arises when passing an already joined query such as `policy_scope(Classroom.find(params[:classroom_id]).exams)`.
ActiveRecord effectively generates a strange query which is unusable because both a_classroom.exams and our scope do a join on :student.

In addition, removing `joins` from our exam scope, giving us `scope.merge(policy_scope(Student))`, makes our call `policy_scope(Classroom.find(params[:classroom_id]).exams)` work while breaking `policy_scope(Exam)`.

Is there a way to work around this so that both use cases work ?
Or is my approach to Pundit wrong ?
Is this the limit of ActiveRecord ?
Any help regarding this would be appreciated !

Answer (score 2):

`policy_scope` is intended to be used from Controllers. For e.g. refer the examples given in section https://github.com/varvet/pundit#scopes and you should find that this method is being demonstrated to be used either from controllers or views.

However as per your code you are trying to use `policy_scope` in your scope classes (i.e classes extending `ApplicationPolicy::Scope` class) themselves. And I think I am understanding the intention behind doing so to reuse the already defined scopes. But in my opinion that's a wrong way to think about it.

Once inside `YourScopeClass#resolve` method you should use normal querying mechanism like you do elsewhere in your Rails application.

I don't have a complete know-how of the fields you have in your model. But based on the comments you have added in `resolve` method for a reviewer, you should do something like:

```
class StudentPolicy::Scope
  def resolve
    if user.reviewer?
      # A reviewer can only see students from classes he's allowed in
      arel = scope.joins(:classroom)
      arel = arel.where(classrooms: { type: : exam, reviewer_id: user.id })
      arel
    end
  end
end
```

Then use it from controller like `policy_scope(Student)`

Similarly

```
class ExamPolicy::Scope
  def resolve
    if user.reviewer?
      # A reviewer can only see/grade exams from students he supervised
      arel = arel.joins(student: [ :classroom ])
      arel = arel.where(classrooms: { type: : exam, reviewer_id: user.id })
      arel
    end
  end
end
```

Then use it from controller like `policy_scope(Exam)`

And if you want to reuse some queries then try creating some generic methods which can be passed the query represented by Pundit Policy Scope.

For e.g.

```
class MyClass
  class << self
    def accessible_students(arel:, user_id:)
      arel.where(classrooms: { type: : exam, reviewer_id: user_id })
    end
  end
end

class StudentPolicy::Scope
  def resolve
    if user.reviewer?
      # A reviewer can only see students from classes he's allowed in

      arel = scope.joins(:classroom)
      arel = MyClass.accessible_students(arel: arel, user_id: user.id)
      arel
    end
  end
end

class ExamPolicy::Scope
  def resolve
    if user.reviewer?
      # A reviewer can only see/grade exams from students he supervised
      arel = arel.joins(student: [ :classroom ])
      arel = MyClass.accessible_students(arel: arel, user_id: user.id)
      arel
    end
  end
end
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: The policy_scope method inside Scope classes is just a helper that calls Pundit.policy_scope! to allow chaining but I do feel it is sort of anti-pattern.

Comment: I understand your point about Pundit's `policy_scope` method. But in my opinion we should take into consideration the usage intention with which a specific method is implemented and exposed publicly. Otherwise nothing restricts us from using any method anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I wanted to put a new line but it published the comment instead. Here's the follow up:

The way you described in your first example of StudentPolicy::Scope doesn't suit me because I wan't to enforce scope dependencies so that changing a users' scope for a parent model automatically trickles down to child scopes.

I do feel it makes sense to have some sort of 'inheritance' at the query level, I just can't figure out how to implement it. I'll try and implement your second example to get a better feel of it though.

Comment: I guess in simpler terms, in you first example, if I say a reviewer has access to a new range of classroom, say `type: :catchup_exams`, I can't be sure a developer will add access to students & exams from those added rooms. The change could be done without knowledge of the exams mechanics and association, which is why I want it to be done automatically.